# How to stretch layout to edges

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I stretch the black to the edges? Id like to do that then put an overflow to make it a bit transparent :)

[image]

Comment: Add the layout code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the dimensions in `dimens.xml`. By default, there is a border of `16dp` around everything, so change that to `0dp`. If you continue to want a border around the `ListView`, you can manually add the padding for that specific object by defining it in the XML layout.

Comment: Missed that one, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried match_parent?  You could also change the margins.